# How to loop through JSON array of JSON objects to see if it contains a value that I am looking for in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Here is an example of the json object

```
rawJSON = [
   {"a":0, "b":7},
   {"a":1, "b":8}, 
   {"a":2, "b":9}
]
```

And I have a table that essentially looks like this.

```
demo Table

id | ...(other columns)      | rawJSON
------------------------------------
0  | ...(other columns info) | [{"a":0, "b":7},{"a":1, "b":8}, {"a":2, "b":9}]
1  | ...(other columns info) | [{"a":0, "b":17},{"a":11, "b":5}, {"a":12, "b":5}]
```

What I want is to return a row which insideRawJSON has value from "a" of less than 2 AND the value from "b" of less than 8. THEY MUST BE FROM THE SAME JSON OBJECT.

Essentially the query would similarly look like this

```
SELECT *
FROM demo
WHERE FOR ANY JSON OBJECT in rawJSON column -> "a" < 2 AND -> "b" < 8
```

And therefore it will return

```
id | ...(other columns)      | rawJSON
------------------------------------
0  | ...(other columns info) | [{"a":0, "b":7},{"a":1, "b":8}, {"a":2, "b":9}]
```

I have searched from several posts here but was not able to figure it out. 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229069/extract-json-array-of-numbers-from-json-array-of-objects
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array

I was thinking of creating a plgpsql function but wasn't able to figure out .

Any advice I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you!!

I would like to avoid cross join lateral because it will slow down a lot.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) already asked and answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery that searches through the array elements together with `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM demo d
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM jsonb_array_elements(d.rawjson) a(e)
                            WHERE (a.e->>'a')::integer < 2
                                  AND (a.e->>'b')::integer < 8);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=76872e404a65baa0e818f87736ed613f)

If the datatype for `rawjson` is `json` rather than `jsonb`, use `json_array_elements()` instead of `jsonb_array_elements()`.